# Telerik reporting in Silverlight, parameters are not arriving to server

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik-reporting

I'm passing parameters this way:

```
        public PrintReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ReportViewer1.RenderBegin += new Telerik.ReportViewer.Silverlight.RenderBeginEventHandler(ReportViewer1_RenderBegin);
    }

    void ReportViewer1_RenderBegin(object sender, Telerik.ReportViewer.Silverlight.RenderBeginEventArgs args)
       {
        args.ParameterValues["ObjectTypeId"] = 40;
        args.ParameterValues["Page"] = 1;
        args.ParameterValues["PageSize"] = 10;
    }
```

And in the server I'm doing this:

```
    public partial class ObjectInstancesReport : Telerik.Reporting.Report
{
    private IEnumerable<ObjectInstance> _objectInstances;

    public ObjectInstancesReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var objectTypeId = this.ReportParameters["ObjectTypeId"].Value == null ? 40 : (int)this.ReportParameters["ObjectTypeId"].Value;
        var searchText = (string)this.ReportParameters["SearchText"].Value;
        var page = this.ReportParameters["Page"].Value == null ? 1 : (int)this.ReportParameters["Page"].Value;
        var pageSize = this.ReportParameters["PageSize"].Value == null ? 20 : (int)this.ReportParameters["PageSize"].Value;
```

but I get only null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, parameters are not available on constructor, need to use this:

```
        public ObjectInstancesReport()
    {
        //
        // Required for telerik Reporting designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        table1.ItemDataBinding += new EventHandler(table1_ItemDataBinding);
        this.DataSource = null;

        this.Report.NeedDataSource += new EventHandler(Report_NeedDataSource);
    }

    void Report_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var objectTypeId = this.ReportParameters["ObjectTypeId"].Value == null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(this.ReportParameters["ObjectTypeId"].Value);
        var searchText = (string)this.ReportParameters["SearchText"].Value;
        var page = this.ReportParameters["Page"].Value == null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(this.ReportParameters["Page"].Value);
        var pageSize = this.ReportParameters["PageSize"].Value == null ? 20 :  Convert.ToInt32(this.ReportParameters["PageSize"].Value);
```